# Instantiating Globally Accessible List After Runtime

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

I have data that I am retrieving from a database and then added into a list with `list1.add()`. List 1 will have its own category of items, ex `Sciencebooks`, List2 will have `Fictionbooks`, List3 will have `Cosmeticbooks`, etc. The issue that I do not know how many lists there will be from the beginning and the database can increase in size at any given time with `list1`, `list2`, `list3`, `list4`,... `list25`... etc, so hardcoding each instance of a new List won't work, especially if they have to be accessed globally.

If data from the category that has an item as `book_type`: `sciencebook`, from what I know I can't create and and name the list a variable `List<Object> (book_type value from data) = new ArrayList<>` when the data is retrieved.

I don't want to create one main list with List because then if I try to keep the index of each category organize, when I need to add new items to separate categories this will increase the index count, I don't want to have to go through increasing each index one by one for one long list versus separate lists. In addition to that, I don't want a very long list to have to cycle/loop through just to retrieve on category.

How can I go about labeling the lists based on the category and have them available globally?

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this might be to use a Map where the keys are the book types and the value is the list of books.

The problem with this solution is that although you fix your initial problem of re-creating similar lists, there is type erasure since we can't know exactly which type of book is stored for each key in the map.

```java
interface Book {
    void read();
}

class ScienceBook implements Book {
    @Override void read() { }
}

class FictionBook implements Book {
    @Override void read() { }
}
enum BookType {
    SCIENCE,
    FICTION;
}

Map<BookType, List<? extends Book>> books = new HashMap<>();

List<Book> books = books.get(BookType.SCIENCE);
```

Comment: Yes. This is the issue I am having of not knowing what type of book might be added at some point in the future and I wont' be able to go in and add a new type of book. That is probably the major problem I'm finding here. If I eventually add, for ex, Cosmology in the database, the BookType wouldn't already have this predefined.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to instead use the service pattern, commonly found in Spring as to easily maintain each list of books. The great thing about this is that you can easily add the functionality to the interface, then use the adapter pattern to create the functionality once, then create a new service when you need it.

Another great aspect of this is that you can use injection libraries like guice to easily manage single instances of these if you want.

```java
    interface Book {
        void read();
    }

    static class ScienceBook implements Book {

        @Override public void read() {
            System.out.println("Science book!");
        }
    }

    static class FictionBook implements Book {
        @Override public void read() {
            System.out.println("Fiction book!");
        }
    }

    interface BookService<B extends Book> {

        List<B> books();

    }

    static abstract class BookServiceAdapter<B extends Book> implements BookService<B> {

        private final List<B> books;

        protected BookServiceAdapter(List<B> books) {
            this.books = books;
        }

        @Override
        public List<B> books() {
            return books;
        }

    }

    static class FictionBookService extends BookServiceAdapter<FictionBook> {

        protected FictionBookService(List<FictionBook> books) {
            super(books);
        }

    }

    static class ScienceBookService extends BookServiceAdapter<ScienceBook> {

        protected ScienceBookService(List<ScienceBook> books) {
            super(books);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BookService<FictionBook> fictionBookService = new FictionBookService(Collections.singletonList(new FictionBook()));

        BookService<ScienceBook> scienceBookService = new ScienceBookService(Collections.singletonList(new ScienceBook()));

        fictionBookService.books().forEach(System.out::println);

        scienceBookService.books().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: As I am unfamiliar with guice, I will have to look into how it works.

Comment: Absolutely. If you need some help let me know.